# Duplicate const error with C++ wrapping C code

Tags: c++, c, c++11, g++4.8

I've got some C code that is included and used from a C++ application, the important parts here:

**C code**

```
ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
endif

...
typedef void* problem_type;

...
int problematic_fn_proto( const problem_type const arg );

ifdef __cplusplus
}
endif
```

Unfortunately, this will not compile due to a `duplicate 'const'` error. It's the `typedef` that causes the problem. If I just change the prototype for the function to:

```
int problematic_fn_proto( const void* const arg );
```

No more problems. Unfortunately, I cannot remove the `typedef`. Is there a solution here? I can make other changes to the C portion, but the typedef and it's use as the argument to the function must remain.

Comment: Note that both `const problem_type` and `problem_type const` are aliases of `void* const` and not `const void* const`.

Comment: @cpplearner please explain. Is it correct to say that `const void* const` means that the address and the values pointed to by the address are immutable?

Comment: Check out any C++ FAQ, it should explain the difference between pointer-to-constant and constant pointer. That said, why can't you fix the code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you're getting this is that now `problem_type` is a type in it's own right, but the only place where double const (const directly before and after a type has the same meaning) makes sense is if you're using pointers. There's a few options if you still want to use `typedef`

First is to not include pointer in the typedef:

```
typedef void problem_type;
int problem_fn_proto( const problem_type* const arg);
```

The second is to include the `const` specifier in the typedef:

```
typedef void const* cproblem_type;
typedef void* problem_type; // non-const variant not used here
int problem_fn_proto(cproblem_type const arg);
```

In the last solution the `cproblem_type` is a pointer to constant data, using `cproblem_type const` means a constant of that (that is a constant pointer to constant data).

Third solution is to notice that constness of an argument doesn't mean much. If the function happens to modify the argument it's not seen from the caller:

```
typedef void const* cproblem_type;
int problem_fn_proto(cproblem_type arg);
```